# How to integrate JSON API in Google blogspot with iOS?

Tags: ios, json, google-api, blogspot

I have experienced in `JSON` API for `wordpress` (`JetPack`) with iOS.

Now i have to write a iOS App for `Blogspot.com` website from Google.

My App is read only and i need to `GET URL` like JetPack Plugin.

Do i need to install Plugin like wordpress in Blogspot.com

I don't have any experienced in `blogspot` and i have no idea where i have to get start.

Could you please guide me the post for developing iOS App with JSON For Blogspot website?

Comment: I am also working on iOS app (blogspot feed to ios). Can you share your app link (both wordpress and blogspot integrated apps).

Answer (score 2):

If the part of the blog you're trying to get is blog posts, here's a generic URL for a JSON feed of posts using the Blogger API (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)):

```
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogID_goes_here/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=10
```

The blogID is in the URL of your blog control panel at blogger.com. Example:

```
https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=blogID_is_here#overview
```

This assumes that blog is public. Retrieving data from private blogs requires authentication.